# How to reliably and efficiently read all error responses from Apple Push Notifications Server in a Java Server?

Tags: java, sockets, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am researching server side development of Apple Push Notifications in Java.
I am using the enhanced format, in order to detect failed messages and resend messages that follow bad messages. I know that Apple to not guarantee the delivery of Push Notifications, but I wish to be able to know whether Apple received my messages and whether the contained any errors.

I noticed that when I try to send an invalid message (invalid device token, too large payload, etc...) to Apple, I can send several more messages before the socket is closed. When the socket is closed it's too late to read the error codes from Apple, so I have no idea which message was the bad one (or even if there was a bad message, since Apple say the connection may close occasionally even when there is no error).

The approach I've seen in the source of JavaPNs to handle this is to read responses from Apple immediately after each message (or group of messages) are sent. The reading from the socket if performed frequently, and waits for a timeout in case there is nothing to read. This is acceptable if you send push notifications infrequently.

If you try to send a large number of notifications in a high frequency (lets say hundreds per second), you can't stop after each message to wait for responses from Apple (even if you wait for a response only for 20ms, that would limit you to 50 messages per second, and you have no way of knowing how long it would take Apple to write the error response, so a short wait may not be enough). If you don't stop to read possible errors after each message, you risk your connection being closed during the sending of messages to Apple, in which case you won't be able to get the Id of the message that caused the connection to close.

Another approach I'm considering is to perform the reads and the writes in separate threads. This way I have a much better chance of getting the error messages from Apple (before the connection is closed) without compromising the speed in which I send messages to Apple. This approach is more complicated programmatically, and since my server is expected to send APNs to multiple iOS applications, each requiring its own socket and reader/writer threads, this will increase the number of threads I need by a factor of two.

All of the above described behavior of the APN Server was learned while attempting to send push notifications to Apple's sandbox server. I'm not sure if the behavior of Apple's production server is better, and I'm not sure it's a good idea to perform my tests on the production server.

My question - Is there a way to reliably read the error responses from Alpha before they close the connection, without sacrificing performance? Is it possible somehow to read input from the socket after it was closed by the server?

Comment: iirc JavaPNs uses SSLSocket and `sslSocket().getOutputSteam.flush()` to detect errors (which doesn't do anything), so the impl. is bogus by design. You can use NIO, SSLEngine, even multiple sockets as the host is resolved to 6-7 IPs, and you do not need more than a single thread. After an error has been detected (by APN server) all pending messages are to be ignored by it. So you have to resend them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, bestsss. I don't understand what you mean by 'You can use NIO, SSLEngine, even multiple sockets as the host is resolved to 6-7 IPs, and you do not need more than a single thread'. Can you elaborate on that please? How can I use a single thread while sending notifications at high speed and still reading the error messages? Do you mean writing to one socket and reading the errors from a different socket? I assume that if you write a message to a given socket, only that same socket will get a possible error reply for that message. Am I wrong?

Comment: It's a pity we didn't release open source version of our APN client with NIO+SSLEngine+ByteBuffers. (if memory serves right, it was some time ago) In short you just send messages and keep an id for each. When you receive `ERROR_RESPONSE(8)` parse the identifier and the messages  'after' the identifier have not been processed by the APN server. Use ring buffer to keep the messages in transit. -> how can accomplish everything in a single thread - NIO in non-blocking mode can serve multiple (well hundreds) of sockets with ten of thousands messages per seconds.

Comment: How often do you read error responses? After every message you push? Is there a significant difference between non-blocking reads and blocking reads with a short timeout? If you use a single thread, wouldn't trying too often to read error responses from Apple reduce the speed in which you can send messages?

Comment: *How often do you read error responses?* **all the time**; *Is there a significant difference between non-blocking reads and blocking reads with a short timeout?* **yes, there is, I'd not do that but it's your choice, you can use 5ms or so** *If you use a single thread, wouldn't trying too often to read error responses from Apple reduce the speed in which you can send messages?* **practically - no, [reading](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) is your main blocking, the only latency is a thread wake up through kernel pipe during the 1st write**

Comment: If you do not use non-blocking NIO you can't use short reads in a single thread, as the write is a blocking operation. So you need another thread just to read all the time. With NIO there is no blocking unless you want that (i.e. no pending writes). Alternative solution is using `InputStream.available()` however on some SSLSocket implementations it might actually block for any available data to come over. Overall I consider SSLSocket deprecated for server-side use.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem as you. And I have tried two approaches, but none of them can reliably read the error responses from Apple before they close the connection :

1. For each socket, I started two threads, one for writing continuously and the other for blocking read. In most cases, the read thread can read the error response when the write encounters "Socket Broken" exception, but it's not completely reliable.
2. For each socket , I started only one thread to write continuously, and when encountered the exception, in the try cache block, try to read the error responses. In most cases, the socket is closed, so I read nothing but an exception.

Comment: Yes, I've also tried the two threads approach and found it to be not 100% reliable. I keep wondering if I'm missing something, since in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html) Apple suggest that it should be possible to read the error response after a write fails.

Comment: Yes, I will continue to look for the right way. Glad to keep communication with you.